# Upgrade from VS Setup MSI to Wix MSI being treated as uninstall

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, setup-project

**Scenario:**

We have used VS 2010 Setup project till now. Migrating new builds to Wix going forward.

**Issue:**

`Msiexec` is treating the upgrade as un-install + fresh-install instead of just upgrade.

**Details:**

- I have used the same `UpgradeCode` Guid for the new WIX setup
- I've added `MajorUpgrade` tag as required
- I've also tried using `Upgrade` and `UpgradeVersion` instead of `MajorUpgrade`
- Version number is updated
- I've restructured WXS to see if it's the issue and it's not

**Note** - System correctly recognizes both as same product and during setup automatically removes the old one.

Problem is, the old product is being run as uninstall rather than as a upgrade.
**I have a custom action set to run during uninstall**, which will remove user-data. Now the issue is, this custom action is being triggered during upgrade for some reason.

This problem doesn't happen if it's `2010 to 2010` or `Wix to Wix`, **Only if it's `2010 to Wix`.**

**Scenarios**

- 1.0(built using 2010) -> 1.1(built using 2010) - No custom action triggered
- 1.0(built using 2010) -> 1.1(built using Wix) - **Uninstall custom action**
- 1.1(built using Wix) -> 1.2(built using Wix) - No custom action triggered

The only difference I've noticed in the logs -

**For VS 2010 to 2010**

```
Action ended: MsiUnpublishAssemblies. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (90:A4) : Skipping action: _[guid].uninstall.SetProperty (condition is false)
MSI (s) (90:A4): Skipping action: _[guid].uninstall (condition is false)
MSI (s) (90:A4) [21:54:10:299]: Doing action: UnpublishComponents
Action start 21:54:10: UnpublishComponents.
```

**For 2010 to WIX -**

```
MsiUnpublishAssemblies. Return value 1.
Doing action: [guid].uninstall.SetProperty
Action start : [guid].uninstall.SetProperty.
MSI (s) (90:D4) : 
Note: 
1: 2235 
2:  
3: ExtendedType 
4: SELECT `Action`,`Type`,`Source`,`Target`, NULL, `ExtendedType` FROM `CustomAction` WHERE `Action` = '[guid].uninstall.SetProperty' 
MSI (s) (90:D4) : PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding [guid].uninstall property. Its value is '/installtype=notransaction /action=uninstall /LogFile= ... "[custom-action].exe" "oldmsi.tmp"'.
Action ended _[guid].SetProperty. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (90:D4) : Doing action: _[guid].uninstall
Action start : _[guid].uninstall.
MSI (s) (90:D4): 
Note: 
1: 2235 
2:  
3: ExtendedType 
4: SELECT `Action`,`Type`,`Source`,`Target`, NULL, `ExtendedType` FROM `CustomAction` WHERE `Action` = '_[guid].uninstall' 
Action ended: _[guid].uninstall. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (90:D4): Doing action: UnpublishComponents
Action start : UnpublishComponents.
```

I'm clueless why this uninstall is happening. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There's not enough information to be sure, but this should help:

A major upgrade always uninstalls the product being upgraded. That is the definition of a major upgrade based on new ProductCode, same UpgradeCode and incremented version and same installation context. This means that your issue depends on your assumptions about an "uninstall custom action"

Visual Studio "uninstall" custom actions are not really "uninstall" custom actions. They are called when the component (denoted by component id) is removed. When you go from VS 2010 built to VS 2010 built the component id remains the same (internally ref counted) and the component remains installed. The same happens with the WiX builds. When you go from VS 2010 built to WiX built the component ids have probably changed, therefore the component from the VS 2010 built MSI is removed, therefore the custom action is called.

In other words the issue is most likely that the component ids in your VS 2010 build (which you cannot see because VS 2010 doesn't even hint at their existence) are not the same as the component ids in your WiX build.

Comment: Ok. I'll see if I can match up the IDs using Wix's Dark and see if it'll help. Do you know of a workaround where I can prevent the uninstall custom action from being executed in the already installed msi?

Comment: if you use "NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE" in the uninstall custom action conditions it will not run when it is being uninstalled due to an upgrade, only when the product is being uninstalled completely.

Comment: The uninstall logic is "hard-coded" in the uninstall of that older product, so you can't change it unless you patch that old product. The "NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE" condition applies to the older product being uninstalled/upgraded, so again you can't add it to the old product without patching it.

Comment: Ah yeah, can't do anything for the already deployed installer unless you want to somehow figureout how to patch it.